# Determining the memory size of a Heroku Dyno Worker from Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, heroku

Is it possible to at lease estimate the total RAM of a Heroku Worker Dyno from Ruby code starting in it? I need this to use just the right number of processes via the https://github.com/salsify/delayed_job_worker_pool gem, so that the processes don't run out of memory.

I have noticed the following Environment variable provided for a Dyno: **ENV[“HEROKU_RAM_LIMIT_MB”]**, and it appears to return correct values, but I'm not sure if it's "official" enough to rely on it. Does anybody know?